# Why when i attach a script to the flashlight nothing happen ?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

What i want to do is when the flashlight is on to be able to rotate the flashlight around with the mouse. But when i attach the script to the Flashlight i'm not getting any errors just nothing happen when i move the mouse around. I tried to attach the script to the GameObject i also tried to attach the script to the EthanRightHand but nothing.

But if i will attach the script to the ThirdPersonController it will rotate the character. But i want to rotate only the flashlight when it's on or to make it maybe nicer to rotate the EthanRightHand when the flashlight is on.

I can make the flashlight in the second script to be public static. But that is not the point. The problem is the first script the ObjectRotator only work on the ThirdPersonController.

[image: Hierarchy and Inspector]

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class ObjectRotator : MonoBehaviour
{
    int speed;
    float friction;
    float lerpSpeed;
    private float xDeg;
    private float yDeg;
    private Quaternion fromRotation;
    private Quaternion toRotation;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        speed = 3;
        friction = 3f;
        lerpSpeed = 3f;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))
        {
            xDeg -= Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * speed * friction;
            yDeg += Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * speed * friction;
            fromRotation = transform.rotation;
            toRotation = Quaternion.Euler(yDeg, xDeg, 0);
            transform.rotation = Quaternion.Lerp(fromRotation, toRotation, Time.deltaTime * lerpSpeed);
        }
    }
}
```

And the flashlight script

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityStandardAssets.Characters.ThirdPerson;

public class Flashlight : MonoBehaviour
{

    [SerializeField]
    Transform someBone;

    Light flashlight;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        flashlight = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Flashlight").GetComponent<Light>();
        transform.parent = someBone;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        transform.localRotation = someBone.localRotation;
        transform.localScale = someBone.localScale;

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.F))
        {
            if (flashlight.enabled)
            {
                flashlight.enabled = false;
            }
            else
            {
                flashlight.enabled = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a `RigidBody` attached to your `GameObject`?

Comment: @Hristo no there is no Rigidbody on the EthanRightHand or on the GameObject or on the Flashlight. But on the GameObject and the Flashlight i have attached Animator component. But no Rigidbody.

Comment: Try `RigidBody` and test again please

Comment: I found what make the problem but not how to solve it. I found that if i remove the Flashlight script from the Flashlight the Object Rotator will work.  But not sure why the Flashlight script make the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are going to make your `FlashLight` a child of the `Hand` you would need to remove these two lines from your code

> transform.localRotation = someBone.localRotation;
>           transform.localScale = someBone.localScale;

Since that will rotate and scale the `FlashLight` as well as the hand.